# Is it possible to add an expiry date type feature?

Tags: feature-request

Someone posted on superuser about desirable machine specs.  It's a fair question but the answers will date rapidly (and to be fair to them they did say "Mid 2009" in the question).

Anyone any thoughts on whether it's desirable to be able to mark questions and/or answers as timeless or "timeful"?

They wouldn't disappear, just be less visible in some way.

If it could be done then the database would clean itself, at least in part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that all answers and edits are timestamped, I'm not sure there is a huge need for this...? **Everything** in IT dates quickly (much more quickly than most sectors) - not just hardware; it would be too high maintenance to try to estimate when your answer dies...

Answer (score 2):

We have a close reason called "No longer relevant" which is used for just this situation. 48 hours after closing for that reason, it can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may have been mentioned someplace in the past. Making it clear that programming/hardware questions are 'old,' should be held in high priority. I remember when I first started trying to learn Visual Basic (.NET), I came across so many classic-VB tutorials, and I had no idea of any differences. Had there been a giant "Don't read this, you moron" flashing like an ipod-ad, I'd be spared some serious frustration :)